# How to fix NoReverseMatch error in Django table for a delete button

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

Python version 3.7.7 and Django version 2.2.3.
**Code on Github**
https://github.com/jcwill415/Stock_Market_Web_App

I want to add a delete button in the last column of a table. When the code is outside of the table, it works to delete an entry from the table. But when the code is inside the table, I receive a NoReverseMatch error that says:

```
  NoReverseMatch at /add_stock.html 
  Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<stock_id>[^/]+)$']

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/add_stock.html
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<stock_id>[^/]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\djangostock\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
Python Executable:  C:\djangostock\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\JCW\\Desktop\\Stock_Market_Web_App-master\\stock',
 'C:\\Users\\JCW\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\JCW\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\JCW\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37',
 'C:\\djangostock\\venv',
 'C:\\djangostock\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**add_stock.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
      <th scope="col">COMPANY</th>
      <th scope="col">STK PRICE</th>
      <th scope="col">PREV CLOSE</th>
      <th scope="col">MARKET CAP</th>
      <th scope="col">VOLUME</th>
      <th scope="col">YTD CHG</th>
      <th scope="col">52 WK HIGH</th>
      <th scope="col">52 WK LOW</th>
      <th scope="col">REMOVE STK</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
{% if ticker %}
      
            {% for list_item in output %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ list_item.symbol }}</th>
                    <td>{{ list_item.companyName }}</td>
                    <td>${{ list_item.latestPrice }}</td/>
                    <td>${{ list_item.previousClose }}</td>
                    <td>${{ list_item.marketCap }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list_item.latestVolume }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list_item.ytdChange }}</td>
                    <td>${{ list_item.week52High }}</td>
                    <td>${{ list_item.week52Low }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-small">Delete {{ item }}</a></br></td>          
        </tr>
        
            {% endfor %}
        
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}

{% for item in ticker %}
    <a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-small">Delete {{ item }}</a> &nbsp;
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def delete(request, stock_id):
    item = Stock.objects.get(pk=stock_id) # call database by primary key for id #
    item.delete()
    messages.success(request, ("Stock Has Been Deleted From Portfolio!"))
    return redirect('add_stock')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('about.html', views.about, name="about"),
    path('add_stock.html', views.add_stock, name="add_stock"),
    path('delete/<stock_id>', views.delete, name="delete"),
    path('news.html', views.news, name="news"),
    
]
```

**What I've Tried**
I've tried using a for loop:

```
{% for item in ticker %}
   <td><a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-small">Delete {{ item }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

But it loops through all the tickers, so there are delete buttons for all entries in the table on each row. If I don't use the for loop, I get the NoReverseMatch error. I know there is a way to solve this, but I have been working on it and searching for over two months.

I've also tried a while loop, and couldn't get it to work. I tried adding a delete form to the add_stock.html file with the corresponding request on the views.py file.

**Links I've tried, but still couldn't solve:**

- [How to fix Django "NoReverseMatch" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099959/how-to-fix-django-noreversematch-error)
- [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'deleted' with no arguments not found. - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192327/noreversematch-reverse-for-deleted-with-no-argu)
- [how to add delete button in each row of my table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616526/how-to-add-delete-button-in-each-row-of-my-table)

ments-not-found-django

Answer (score 1):

You are using `delete` in 2 different places.  In the first, you reference the wrong item:

```
{% for list_item in output %}
   ...
   {% url 'delete' item.id %}
```

should be

```
{% url 'delete' list_item.id %}
```

In the second one, it is correct:

```
{% for item in ticker %}
   <a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}"
```

Also, `delete` is a reserved word in many cases.  I don't think that is the case here, but is still a bad habit.  Change to `delete_stock` everywhere:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_stock' list_item.id %}" ...>

def delete_stock(request, stock_id=None):

path('delete_stock/<stock_id>', views.delete_stock, name="delete_stock"),
```

Is `stock_id` an integer or string?  To find out, print inside the loop in `add_stock()`:

```
api = json.loads(api_request.content)
print(api)
output.append(api)
```

Also, the stock ID will come over as a string in the url, so if it is an integer, do:

```
item = Stock.objects.get(pk=int(stock_id))
```

or use:

```
path('delete_stock/<int:stock_id>', views.delete_stock, name="delete_stock"),
```

Do the other urls work?

**BONUS HINT:**

There is no need to have `.html` in your urls.  That looks antiquated.  Better form would be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('about', views.about, name="about"),
    path('add_stock', views.add_stock, name="add_stock"),
    path('delete_stock/<int:stock_id>', views.delete_stock, name="delete_stock"),
    path('news', views.news, name="news"),
    
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried updating it to {% url 'delete' list_item.id %} and delete the second one. But I still received the NoReverseMatch error. Is there a problem with the url as well, in the urls.py file?

Comment: To troubleshoot, add this to urls: `path('delete_stock', views.delete_stock, name="delete_stock"),`, `path('delete_stock/', views.delete_stock, name="delete_stock"),`. and then test for `stock_id` in the view.  This will tell you if the problem is in your `{{output}}` in the template

Comment: Also, `print(api)` as in edit above to see what you're actually getting.  You may be sending an empty list